# Coding Bat String challenge is failing tests

Tags: java, string

```
public int countYZ(String str) {
  int count = 0;
  for(int i = 0;i<str.length();i++)
    if((str.charAt(i)=='y'||str.charAt(i)=='z')&&!(Character.isLetter(i+1)))
        count++;
  return count;
}
```

This code is failing the test for this criteria : Given a string, count the number of words ending in 'y' or 'z' -- so the 'y' in "heavy" and the 'z' in "fez" count, but not the 'y' in "yellow" (not case sensitive). We'll say that a y or z is at the end of a word if there is not an alphabetic letter immediately following it. (Note: Character.isLetter(char) tests if a char is an alphabetic letter.)

I tracked it by hand and cannot seem to figure out why it isn't working for many of the tests. For example, in "day fyyyz" it outputs 5 but it should be returning 2. Appreciate the help!

Comment: You are counting every single occurrence of 'y' or 'z' you have no logic in place to check whether it's the last letter of a word or not

Comment: Why not just check if the `str.charAt(i+1)=' '`

Comment: @UnholySheep !(Character.isLetter(i+1)) checks if there is a letter after it, why would it count the three y's in "fyyyz" since there is a letter after all three of them

Comment: `!(Character.isLetter(i+1))` checks whether the value of `i+1` (defined as a unicode code point: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter(int)) is a letter or not - you are not passing the actual character of the string into it

Comment: @Ishnark Because a space is not the only non letter character, could have "!" or ":" etc

Comment: @UnholySheep I understand, didn't realize that at first. Thank you!

Comment: Consider that you need to count a `y` or `z` at the end of the string too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to consider:

1. As pointed out by UnholySheep, `Character.isLetter(i+1)` isn't checking the `i+1`th character in the string. You'd need to use:

   ```
   Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i+1))
   ```
2. But simply changing that can yield an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, because you overrun the end of the string if the string ends with a `y` or `z`. So, change the second bit of the condition to

   ```
   !(i+1 != str.length() && Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i+1)))
   ```

   This also counts the `y` or `z` at the end of the string.

   Of course, this can be written as:

   ```
   i+1 == str.length() || !Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i+1))
   ```

   which is a bit less awkward.

Overall condition:

```
if((str.charAt(i) == 'y' || str.charAt(i) == 'z')
    && (i+1 == str.length() || !Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i+1)))
```

If you want to make it case insensitive, use `Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(i))` before comparing to `y` and `z`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem easy to solve with a regex:

```
  String str = "day fyyyz provaz provy drad";
  Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\b\\w+[zy]\\b").matcher(str);
  int i = 0;
  while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
    i++;
  }
  System.out.println("found " + i);
```

This code will output:

```
day
fyyyz
provaz
provy
found 4
```

This regex `(?i)\\b\\w+[zy]\\b` means:

- `(?i)` enable match case insensitive
- `\b` match word boundary
- `\w+` match one or more word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
- `[zy]` Match a single character present in the list below [zy]
- `\b` match word boundary

https://regex101.com/r/tLMobI/1

Answer (score 0):

Your function is return the total number of `y` and `z` characters in the string instead of the number of words *ending* in `y` or `z`. `\\W` is a regular expression token to target any *non-word* character in a string.

```
public int countYZ(String str) {
    String[] words = str.split("\\W");
    int tally = 0;

    for (String w : words)
        tally += (w.endsWith("y") || w.endsWith("z")) ? 1 : 0;

    return tally;
}
```